# Choose encoding for pdftohtml

Tags: linux, xml, pdf, terminal, pdf-to-html

How can I force pdftohtml output to be UTF 8?

```
$ pdftohtml -enc utf8 my.pdf 
Error: Couldn't find unicodeMap file for the 'utf-8' encoding
```

And `-listenc` doesn't seem to be a valid option.

I think it is using ISO-8859-1 by default (although for some reason VIM reads the file and special characters fine even though `:set enc?` reports `utf-8`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the command by using `pdftohtml -enc UTF-8 file.pdf`
Like:

```
$ pdftohtml -enc UTF-8 my.pdf
```